# QObjectList and QList Differences

Tags: qt, qobject, qlist

What are the differences between `QObjectList` and `QList`? 
Can they be used interchangeably? If not, can a `QList` be cast to a `QObjectList` and vice versa?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**`QObjectList`** is an alias for `QList<QObject *>`.

**`QList<T>`** is a template class for lists of type *T*.

In other words, **`QList<T>`** is a generic class for lists of any type. **`QObjectList`** is a special case of *QList*, where *T* is a *QObject* pointer.

Answer (score 1):

`QList` is the generic template version for lists.

`QObjectList` is a 'list of pointers to `QObject`s' and basically just a typedef on `QList<QObject*>`